# Handling escaped quotes with Python's csv.reader

Tags: python, csv, escaping, quotes

Using python's `csv` module, I'm trying to read some CSV data.

I'm using the code:

```
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csv_file.read(1024))
csv_file.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, dialect)

for line in reader:
    ...
```

Everything works fine except for lines containing escaped quotes:

```
11837,2,NULL,"\"The Take Over, The Breaks Over\"","Fall Out Boy"
```

Such a line is tokenized as:

```
['11837', '2', 'NULL', '\\The Take Over', ' The Breaks Over\\""', 'Fall Out Boy']
```

The dialect contains the following properties:

```
dialect.quotechar = "
dialect.quoting = 0
dialect.escapechar = None
dialect.delimiter = ,
dialect.doublequote = False
dialect.lineterminator = \n
```

Is there anything I can do besides writing my own CSV parser?

Comment: Ahright, I've written my own parser already :)

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not mistaken, `dialect.escapechar = None` should be `dialect.escapechar = '\\'`

[If you look at the examples in the docs](http://pymotw.com/2/csv/), it certainly seems to suggest making that alteration

Comment: I've already tried setting ``dialect.escapechar = '\\'``, but the result remains the same :(

Comment: Oh, also set  `dialect.quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`.